# Alter table or reset auto-increment using CDbMigration

Tags: php, mysql, yii, auto-increment

How can I alter table or [reset the auto-increment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8923132/1469208) of a field in Yii 1.x, using [`CDbMigration`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration/)?

I found [`alterColumn`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration#alterColumn-detail) method, as good as [`createTable`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration#createTable-detail), [`dropTable`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration#dropTable-detail), [`renameTable`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration#renameTable-detail) and [`truncateTable`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration#truncateTable-detail) methods, but either I'm blind or there isn't anything for altering table or resetting the auto-increment of particular column or field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**execute()**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration#execute-detail) as Yii defines it:

> Executes a SQL statement. This method executes the specified SQL statement using dbConnection.

So,

```
$this->execute("ALTER TABLE tbl_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect answer. I have a [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27403885/1469208) problem, covering `CDbMigration`. Maybe you can help as well?

Comment: starting from YY 2.0.16 you can do it this way `$this->executeResetSequence('tbl_name', '1');`